# How to trim after 1 letter from space C#?

Tags: c#, string, trim

Hello I'm trying to take out the first word and the first from the second and with no blank space from a string but I got no success. How can I do it?

Example:
I have the words: HELLO WORLD! and I want to get: HELLOW
Or: LAPTOP COVER and get LAPTOPC

There's no limit of letters for the first word. Thank you all!

Comment: Have you made any attempt on your own? We're not going to write your code for you.

Comment: [Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) on space, then append the first char from the 2nd string to the first string.

Comment: I was using Trim but it was only taking out blank spaces and when I wrote the second word the spaces appears. Also thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 string s = "HELLO WORLD!";
 string[] s1 = s.Split(' ');
 string outchar = s1[0] + s1[1].Substring(0, 1);
```

Comment: why downvote ?is it wrong?

Comment: Sorry, clic mistake. It worked correctly. I wasn't using Split. Thank you